# Is there a common Java method to trim every string in an object graph?

Tags: java, string, reflection, object-graph

I'm hoping to trim all Strings that are part of an object graph.

So I have an object graph like so

```
 RootElement
   - name (String)
   - adjective (String)
   - items ArrayOfItems
     - getItems (List<Item>)
       - get(i) (Item)
       Item
         - name (String)
         - value (double)
         - alias (String)
         - references ArrayOfReferences
           - getReferences (List<Reference>)
             - get(i) (Reference)
             Reference
               - prop1 (String)
               - prop2 (Integer)
               - prop3 (String)
```

There is a get and set pair for every property of every class represented in this object graph.  Ideally every field of type String would end up trimmed, including enumerating any child objects contained in collections.  There are no cycles contained within the object graph.

Is there any java library that implements some sort of generic object graph visitor pattern or String\Reflection utility library that does this?

An external third party library that does this would also be fine, it does not have to be part of the standard java libraries.

Comment: Doable using reflection. Sensible if you have many classes, and cannot construct the objects in a clean, trimmed way.

Comment: I realize this is doable using reflection, but I was hoping for something more simple than implementing my own reflective search\visitor.

Comment: And [bean validation](http://beanvalidation.org/) is probably too late and circumstantial and littering with a `@Trim` annotation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Below is the explanation of solution that I have built using Java Reflection API. I have posted the working code (with its url to github) below. This solution mainly uses:

1. Java Reflection API
2. Independent handling of Java Collections
3. Recursion

To start with, I have used [`Introspector`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/Introspector.html) to go over the `readMethods` of the `Class` omitting the methods defined for `Object`

```
for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : Introspector
                    .getBeanInfo(c, Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
            Method method = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
```

### Cases

1. If the current level of `Property` is of type `String`
2. If its an `Object` Array of Properties
3. If its a `String` array
4. If its a type of Java `Collection` class
5. Separate placement for `Map` with special conditions to process its *keys* and *values*

This utility uses the Java Reflection API to traverse through an object graph with disciplined syntax of *getters* and *setters* and trims all strings encountered within an `Object` graph recursively.

### Code

This entire util class with the main test class (and custom data types/pojos) is [here on my github](https://github.com/popofibo/TrimObjectGraph)

Usage:

```
myObj = (MyObject) SpaceUtil.trimReflective(myObj);
```

**Util method:**

```
    public static Object trimReflective(Object object) throws Exception {
        if (object == null)
            return null;

        Class<? extends Object> c = object.getClass();
        try {
            // Introspector usage to pick the getters conveniently thereby
            // excluding the Object getters
            for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : Introspector
                    .getBeanInfo(c, Object.class).getPropertyDescriptors()) {
                Method method = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
                String name = method.getName();

                // If the current level of Property is of type String
                if (method.getReturnType().equals(String.class)) {
                    String property = (String) method.invoke(object);
                    if (property != null) {
                        Method setter = c.getMethod("set" + name.substring(3),
                                new Class<?>[] { String.class });
                        if (setter != null)
                            // Setter to trim and set the trimmed String value
                            setter.invoke(object, property.trim());
                    }
                }

                // If an Object Array of Properties - added additional check to
                // avoid getBytes returning a byte[] and process
                if (method.getReturnType().isArray()
                        && !method.getReturnType().isPrimitive()
                        && !method.getReturnType().equals(String[].class)
                        && !method.getReturnType().equals(byte[].class)) {
                    System.out.println(method.getReturnType());
                    // Type check for primitive arrays (would fail typecasting
                    // in case of int[], char[] etc)
                    if (method.invoke(object) instanceof Object[]) {
                        Object[] objectArray = (Object[]) method.invoke(object);
                        if (objectArray != null) {
                            for (Object obj : (Object[]) objectArray) {
                                // Recursively revisit with the current property
                                trimReflective(obj);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // If a String array
                if (method.getReturnType().equals(String[].class)) {
                    String[] propertyArray = (String[]) method.invoke(object);
                    if (propertyArray != null) {
                        Method setter = c.getMethod("set" + name.substring(3),
                                new Class<?>[] { String[].class });
                        if (setter != null) {
                            String[] modifiedArray = new String[propertyArray.length];
                            for (int i = 0; i < propertyArray.length; i++)
                                if (propertyArray[i] != null)
                                    modifiedArray[i] = propertyArray[i].trim();

                            // Explicit wrapping
                            setter.invoke(object,
                                    new Object[] { modifiedArray });
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Collections start
                if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(method.getReturnType())) {
                    Collection collectionProperty = (Collection) method
                            .invoke(object);
                    if (collectionProperty != null) {
                        for (int index = 0; index < collectionProperty.size(); index++) {
                            if (collectionProperty.toArray()[index] instanceof String) {
                                String element = (String) collectionProperty
                                        .toArray()[index];

                                if (element != null) {
                                    // Check if List was created with
                                    // Arrays.asList (non-resizable Array)
                                    if (collectionProperty instanceof List) {
                                        ((List) collectionProperty).set(index,
                                                element.trim());
                                    } else {
                                        collectionProperty.remove(element);
                                        collectionProperty.add(element.trim());
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                // Recursively revisit with the current property
                                trimReflective(collectionProperty.toArray()[index]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // Separate placement for Map with special conditions to process
                // keys and values
                if (method.getReturnType().equals(Map.class)) {
                    Map mapProperty = (Map) method.invoke(object);
                    if (mapProperty != null) {
                        // Keys
                        for (int index = 0; index < mapProperty.keySet().size(); index++) {
                            if (mapProperty.keySet().toArray()[index] instanceof String) {
                                String element = (String) mapProperty.keySet()
                                        .toArray()[index];
                                if (element != null) {
                                    mapProperty.put(element.trim(),
                                            mapProperty.get(element));
                                    mapProperty.remove(element);
                                }
                            } else {
                                // Recursively revisit with the current property
                                trimReflective(mapProperty.get(index));
                            }

                        }
                        // Values
                        for (Map.Entry entry : (Set<Map.Entry>) mapProperty
                                .entrySet()) {

                            if (entry.getValue() instanceof String) {
                                String element = (String) entry.getValue();
                                if (element != null) {
                                    entry.setValue(element.trim());
                                }
                            } else {
                                // Recursively revisit with the current property
                                trimReflective(entry.getValue());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else {// Catch a custom data type as property and send through
                        // recursion
                    Object property = (Object) method.invoke(object);
                    if (property != null) {
                        trimReflective(property);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Strings cannot be trimmed because: ", e);
        }

        return object;

    }
```

### Test

I also have a test class in there which creates a relatively complex object. The test class has different scenarios that cover:

1. `String` properties
2. Properties as custom datatypes which in turn have `String` properties
3. Properties as custom datatypes which in turn have properties as custom datatypes which in turn have `String` properties
4. `List` of custom data types
5. `Set` of `Strings`
6. `Array` of custom data types
7. `Array` of `Strings`
8. `Map` of `String` and custom data type

### Object Graph:

[image]

### Test Object Code Snippet:

```
public static Music buildObj() {
        Song song1 = new Song();
        Song song2 = new Song();
        Song song3 = new Song();

    Artist artist1 = new Artist();
    Artist artist2 = new Artist();

    song1.setGenre("ROCK       ");
    song1.setSonnet("X    ");
    song1.setNotes("Y    ");
    song1.setCompostions(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "SOME X DATA  ",
            "SOME OTHER DATA X ", "SOME MORE DATA X    ", " " }));

    Set<String> instruments = new HashSet<String>();
    instruments.add("         GUITAR    ");
    instruments.add("         SITAR    ");
    instruments.add("         DRUMS    ");
    instruments.add("         BASS    ");

    song1.setInstruments(instruments);

    song2.setGenre("METAL       ");
    song2.setSonnet("A    ");
    song2.setNotes("B    ");
    song2.setCompostions(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "SOME Y DATA  ",
            "          SOME OTHER DATA Y ",
            "           SOME MORE DATA Y    ", " " }));

    song3.setGenre("POP       ");
    song3.setSonnet("DONT    ");
    song3.setNotes("KNOW     ");
    song3.setCompostions(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "SOME Z DATA  ",
            "               SOME OTHER DATA Z ",
            "          SOME MORE DATA Z   ", " " }));

    artist1.setSongList(Arrays.asList(new Song[] { song1, song3 }));

    artist2.setSongList(Arrays.asList(new Song[] { song1, song2, song3 }));
    Map<String, Person> artistMap = new HashMap<String, Person>();
    Person tutor1 = new Person();
    tutor1.setName("JOHN JACKSON DOE       ");
    artistMap.put("          Name                 ", tutor1);

    Person coach1 = new Person();
    coach1.setName("CARTER   ");
    artistMap.put("Coach      ", coach1);
    artist2.setTutor(artistMap);

    music.setSongs(Arrays.asList(new Song[] { song1, song2, song3 }));
    music.setArtists(Arrays.asList(new Artist[] { artist1, artist2 }));

    music.setLanguages(new String[] { "    ENGLISH    ", "FRENCH    ",
            "HINDI    " });
    Person singer1 = new Person();
    singer1.setName("DAVID      ");

    Person singer2 = new Person();
    singer2.setName("JACOB      ");
    music.setSingers(new Person[] { singer1, singer2 });

    Human man = new Human();
    Person p = new Person();
    p.setName("   JACK'S RAGING BULL   ");
    SomeGuy m = new SomeGuy();
    m.setPerson(p);
    man.setMan(m);

    music.setHuman(man);

    return music;
}
```

### Outcome:

```
#######BEFORE#######
>>[>>DAVID      ---<<, >>JACOB      ---<<]---[    ENGLISH    , FRENCH    , HINDI    ]---[>>ROCK       ---X    ---Y    ---[SOME X DATA  , SOME OTHER DATA X , SOME MORE DATA X    ,  ]---[         SITAR    ,          GUITAR    ,          BASS    ,          DRUMS    ]<<, >>METAL       ---A    ---B    ---[SOME Y DATA  ,           SOME OTHER DATA Y ,            SOME MORE DATA Y    ,  ]---<<, >>POP       ---DONT    ---KNOW     ---[SOME Z DATA  ,                SOME OTHER DATA Z ,           SOME MORE DATA Z   ,  ]---<<]---[>>---[>>ROCK       ---X    ---Y    ---[SOME X DATA  , SOME OTHER DATA X , SOME MORE DATA X    ,  ]---[         SITAR    ,          GUITAR    ,          BASS    ,          DRUMS    ]<<, >>POP       ---DONT    ---KNOW     ---[SOME Z DATA  ,                SOME OTHER DATA Z ,           SOME MORE DATA Z   ,  ]---<<]<<, >>{Coach      =>>CARTER    ---<<,           Name                 =>>JOHN JACKSON DOE       ---<<}---[>>ROCK       ---X    ---Y    ---[SOME X DATA  , SOME OTHER DATA X , SOME MORE DATA X    ,  ]---[         SITAR    ,          GUITAR    ,          BASS    ,          DRUMS    ]<<, >>METAL       ---A    ---B    ---[SOME Y DATA  ,           SOME OTHER DATA Y ,            SOME MORE DATA Y    ,  ]---<<, >>POP       ---DONT    ---KNOW     ---[SOME Z DATA  ,                SOME OTHER DATA Z ,           SOME MORE DATA Z   ,  ]---<<]<<]---=>   JACK'S RAGING BULL   <=<<
Number of spaces : 644
#######AFTER#######
>>[>>DAVID---<<, >>JACOB---<<]---[ENGLISH, FRENCH, HINDI]---[>>ROCK---X---Y---[SOME X DATA, SOME OTHER DATA X, SOME MORE DATA X, ]---[GUITAR, SITAR, DRUMS, BASS]<<, >>METAL---A---B---[SOME Y DATA, SOME OTHER DATA Y, SOME MORE DATA Y, ]---<<, >>POP---DONT---KNOW---[SOME Z DATA, SOME OTHER DATA Z, SOME MORE DATA Z, ]---<<]---[>>---[>>ROCK---X---Y---[SOME X DATA, SOME OTHER DATA X, SOME MORE DATA X, ]---[GUITAR, SITAR, DRUMS, BASS]<<, >>POP---DONT---KNOW---[SOME Z DATA, SOME OTHER DATA Z, SOME MORE DATA Z, ]---<<]<<, >>{Name=>>JOHN JACKSON DOE---<<, Coach=>>CARTER---<<}---[>>ROCK---X---Y---[SOME X DATA, SOME OTHER DATA X, SOME MORE DATA X, ]---[GUITAR, SITAR, DRUMS, BASS]<<, >>METAL---A---B---[SOME Y DATA, SOME OTHER DATA Y, SOME MORE DATA Y, ]---<<, >>POP---DONT---KNOW---[SOME Z DATA, SOME OTHER DATA Z, SOME MORE DATA Z, ]---<<]<<]---=>JACK'S RAGING BULL<=<<
Number of spaces : 111
```

There is a non-zero count of the number of spaces in the above *trimmed* output because I didn't make an effort to override `toString` of any collections (`List`, `Set`) or `Map`. There are certain improvements to the code I want to make but for your case the solution should work just fine.

### Limitations *(further improvements)*

1. Cannot handle undisciplined syntax of properties (invalid getters/setters)
2. Cannot handle chained Collections: for example, `List<List<Person>>` - because of the exclusive support to disciplined getters/setters convention
3. No Guava collection library support

Answer (score 10):

No, there's no built-in traversal for something like this, and remember that Java `String`s are immutable, so you can't actually trim in place--you have to trim and replace. Some objects may not permit modification of their `String` variables.

Answer (score 4):

I made a simple method for trimming String values with Reflection API.

```
public Object trimStringValues(Object model){
  for(Field field : model.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
        try{
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(model);
        String fieldName = field.getName();
         if(value != null){
            if(value instanceof String){
                String trimmed = (String) value;
                field.set(model, trimmed.trim());
                }

            }
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
}
```

I haven't bumped in to any problems with this one yet. I know its an old thread, but it might help somone whos is looking for something simple.

Answer (score 4):

Building off @SwissArmyKnife I converted his simple String trimming function into an interface with a default method.  So any object where you would like to use object.trim(), you just have to add "implements Trimmable".

Simple String trim interface: Trimmable.class

```
/**
 * Utility interface that trims all String fields of the implementing class.
 */
public interface Trimmable {

    /**
     * Trim all Strings
     */
    default void trim(){
        for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                Object value = field.get(this);
                if (value != null){
                    if (value instanceof String){
                        String trimmed = (String) value;
                        field.set(this, trimmed.trim());
                    }
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An object that we would like to be trimmable: Person.class (implements Trimmable interface)

```
public class Person implements Trimmable {
     private String firstName;
     private String lastName;
     private int age;

     // getters/setters omitted
}
```

Now you can use person.trim()

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setFirstName("    John   ");
person.setLastName("  Doe");
person.setAge(30);
person.trim();
```